# Buid iOS apps without embedding a provisionig profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am developing some apps for Distribution within the enterprise.

Is there any way, I can build the apps without XCode embedding the distribution profile, that way I can push a renewed profile via a Mobile Device Management solution when the old one expires without requiring to rebuild the apps.

Thanks

Comment: you need an enterprise developer program for that https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: I am already part of the Enterprise Development program.
I already have the apps deployed with the embedded profile but I want to re-build them without a profile so that when the profile expires, I can just push the renewed profile without rebuilding the apps

What do I need to do as a next step ?

Comment: I'm not member of a Enterprise Development program, but i guess you can distribute apps that don't expire using a distribution profile and you can update them wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossibile, the provisioning profile is required to create ipa